# i would like to aggregate a table in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to return the following

```
sales_person        year            count(sales_id)          avg(delivery_duration)
jim                 2019                 56                          5
jim                 2020                 34                          4
jim                 2021                 84                          3
```

how would i do this in sql

so far I have

```
select sales_person,
       extract(year from sales_date),
       count(sales_id),
       avg(delivery_duration)
from table
```

Comment: "I would like to return the following" from what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I recommend to you to avoid using word table for table name. In my  demo I used word test.
- All you had to add in your try is a group by
  clause In the group by clause you HAVE to add all the columns you
  have selected and did not used in aggregate functions and you can
  also add some extra columns from the table that are not in your
  select if you wish.

  ```
  select sales_person,
      extract(year from sales_date),
      count(sales_id),
      avg(delivery_duration)
  from test
  group by sales_person
           , extract(year from sales_date)
  ```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d5d8dc6895435a8ae03ca7992846b7a8)

Comment: thanks also thanks again because of the useful link you have shared ill be using the dbfiddle site to work on improving my sql

Answer (score 0):

Just as you posted it, just add `group by` for non-aggregated columns:

```
select sales_person,
       extract(year from sales_date),
       count(sales_id),
       avg(delivery_duration)
from table
group by sales_person,
         extract(year from sales_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
select sales_person,
       extract(year from sales_date),
       count(sales_id),
       avg(delivery_duration)
from   table_name
GROUP BY
       sales_person,
       extract(year from sales_date)
```